# fastboot fails with mediatek 6572

Tags: fastboot

I have issue with fastboot which get hangs on erasing.
Can't it work with mediatek 6572 ?

```
C:\Users\ransh>fastboot devices
0123456789ABCDEF        fastboot


C:\Users\ransh>fastboot flash system system.img
target didn't report max-download-size
erasing 'system'...
```

Thanks,
Ran

Comment: Flash with SP Flashtool. You need a scatter file, otherwise it won't work

Comment: can I flash just one image (like system.img). it takes too long to flash all images ?

Comment: Download the flash files, you get all files. Just load what you want to be flashed. Have you ever flashed with SP Flashtool before ?

Comment: Thank you! just one thing. what's the added value of mtk droid to sp flash tool ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: to load just what I want (with spi flash) I need to put in folder only the required file (like system.img) and remove the others ?

Comment: Not necessary to remove. Download the firmware, Unzip it, Download SP Flashtool, install it then run it. Click on Scatter file inside SP Flashtool, browse where you unzipped the firmware and select a text file xxxxxxxxxxx.txt (the only one that appears), it will load all files into SP Flashtool, uncheck what you don't need to flash

Comment: So the answer, according to your comments: need to use mtk sp flash tool. fastboot doesn't work with mtk (for some reason). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you solve your problem ?

Comment: I want to backup system.img and userdata.img partitions and then flash them back, so as I understand I need to use mtk droid and then sp flash tool. using fastboot was much more effecient.

Comment: Why do you need to back up when you can have the ROM which contains what you need.

Comment: Give a try to MTK Droid : Connect the phone with ADB. Download here: https://androidmtk.com/download-mtk-droid-tool